# AfterClass is not running for all objects in dataprovider when there are multiple providers

Tags: testng

I have multiple data providers in my test class.

```
@Factory(dataProvider = "userModeDataProvider")
public APIM678ApplicationCreationTestCase(TestUserMode userMode) {
    this.userMode = userMode;
}

@DataProvider
public static Object[][] userModeDataProvider() {
    return new Object[][]{
            new Object[]{TestUserMode.TENANT_ADMIN},
            new Object[]{TestUserMode.SUPER_TENANT_ADMIN},
    };
}

@DataProvider(name = "createApplicationWithValidData")
public static Object[][] createAppWithValidDataProvider() throws Exception {

    return new Object[][]{
            {"NewApplication1", tier, callBackUrl, description},
            {"NewApplication2", tier, callBackUrl, ""},
            {"NewApplication3", tier, "", description},
            {"NewApplication4", tier, "", ""}
    };
}

@DataProvider(name = "createApplicationWithInValidData")
public static Object[][] createAppWithInValidDataProvider() throws Exception {
    return new Object[][]{
            {"", tier, "", ""},//name is empty
            {"NewApplication5", "", callBackUrl, description},
            {"", "", callBackUrl, description},
    };
}
```

BeforeClass is running for both "userModeDataProvider" objects.

BeforeClass is running for both objects in "userModeDataProvider" data provider. (TestUserMode.TENANT_ADMIN & TestUserMode.SUPER_TENANT_ADMIN). But affter class is running only for the first object in that data provider(**TestUserMode.TENANT_ADMIN**).

What could be the possible reason for this ?

Comment: You should share a more complete example: add a `@Test` method and the `@BeforeClass` methods.